# udev tag systemd not set on boot for compute module 3 eMMC

Tags: linux, systemd, udev

**systemd version the issue has been seen with**
systemd 246

**Used distribution**
embedded linux, build with buildroot

**Linux kernel version used** (`uname -a`)

`Linux 5.9.16-v7 #28 SMP Wed Jul 14 17:26:47 CEST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux`

**CPU architecture issue was seen on**
Raspberry Pi compute module 3

**Expected behaviour you didn't see**
Automatic mounting of eMMC partitions of compute module 3 via mount units after boot.

**Unexpected behaviour you saw**
The systemd tag for the block devices is only set after executing
`udevadm test -a change /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p[1,2]`
With no other command or udev rule we could set the tag.

`systemd-udevd.service` is running, but is not picking up the block devices for some reason.

My only idea at this moment is that the eMMC storage is for some reason not picked up as a block device at boot time and for that the default systemd udev rule does not apply.

/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:

`SUBSYSTEM=="block", TAG+="systemd"`

udevadm info before executing `udevadm test -a change`:

```
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0
N: mmcblk0
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: MAJOR=179
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block

#udevadm info /dev/mmcblk0p1
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1
N: mmcblk0p1
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0p1
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: PARTN=1
E: MAJOR=179
E: MINORudevadm test -a change /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=block

#udevadm info /dev/mmcblk0p2
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2
N: mmcblk0p2
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0p2
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: PARTN=2
E: MAJOR=179
E: MINOR=2
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
```

udevadm info after executing `udevadm test -a change`:

```
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0
N: mmcblk0
L: 0
S: disk/by-path/platform-3f202000.mmc
S: disk/by-id/mmc-4FTE4R_0xbe81f48a
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: MAJOR=179
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5807576958
E: ID_SERIAL=0xbe81f48a
E: ID_NAME=4FTE4R
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f202000.mmc
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f202000_mmc
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=bcb63fb5
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-path/platform-3f202000.mmc /dev/disk/by-id/mmc-4FTE4R_0xbe81f48a
E: TAGS=:systemd:

# udevadm info /dev/mmcblk0p1
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1
N: mmcblk0p1
L: 0
S: disk/by-partuuid/bcb63fb5-01
S: disk/by-uuid/29B5-FCDC
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0p1
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: PARTN=1
E: MAJOR=179
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5797473791
E: ID_FS_UUID=29B5-FCDC
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=29B5-FCDC
E: ID_FS_VERSION=FAT16
E: ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=bcb63fb5-01
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0xc
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_FLAGS=0x80
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2048
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=819200
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=179:0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/bcb63fb5-01 /dev/disk/by-uuid/29B5-FCDC
E: TAGS=:systemd:

# udevadm info /dev/mmcblk0p2
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2
N: mmcblk0p2
L: 0
S: disk/by-uuid/0c4261bf-59d5-4d14-b474-e936a0a55e59
S: disk/by-partuuid/bcb63fb5-02
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f202000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/mmcblk0p2
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: PARTN=2
E: MAJOR=179
E: MINOR=2
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5799911394
E: ID_FS_UUID=0c4261bf-59d5-4d14-b474-e936a0a55e59
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=0c4261bf-59d5-4d14-b474-e936a0a55e59
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=bcb63fb5-02
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0x83
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=2
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=821248
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=6813696
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=179:0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-uuid/0c4261bf-59d5-4d14-b474-e936a0a55e59 /dev/disk/by-partuuid/bcb63fb5-02
E: TAGS=:systemd:
```

**Steps to reproduce the problem**
Found no way till now to reproduce the problem on different systems.

**Additional program output to the terminal or log subsystem illustrating the issue**